# Can anyone explain this paragraph of the current C++0x standard draft?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, one-definition-rule

Can anyone explain this statement from ISO N3242 §3.2, 2nd point

> A member of a set of candidate functions is odr-used if it is selected by 
>   overload resolution when referred to from a potentiallyevaluated expression.
>   [ Note: This covers calls to named functions (5.2.2), operator overloading
>   (Clause 13),user-defined conversions (12.3.2), allocation function for 
>   placement new (5.3.4), as well as non-default initialization(8.5).

ISO Standard 2003 : says

> An overloaded function is used if it is selected by overload resolution when 
>   referred to from a potentially-evaluated expression. [Note: this covers calls 
>   to named functions (5.2.2), operator overloading (clause 13), user-defined
>   conversions (12.3.2), allocation function for placement new (5.3.4),
>   as well as non-default initialization (8.5).

What is the actual difference in these statements?

Can any one explain this with the help of an example/program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terminology "overloaded function" is (slightly) ambiguous between referring to the member or to the set. C++11 clarifies that functions that are never selected from a potentially-evaluated expression are not odr-used.

The term "odr-used" is new with C++11. It essentially means that the given object might be represented in the final, compiled binary file, and that the [one-definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) applies.

Answer (score 4):

The paragraph was changed to fix the [Core Issue #1174](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1174). There you can find the example which shows the difference.

Comment: I think that applies more to the preceding sentence, "A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure," which was not ultimately changed from C++03. Perhaps they decided that "if" was alright because it is not "if and only if", and the odr-use is implied by the overload selection rule.

Comment: @Krill : what they explained is exactly not this statement(full) ... right ?

Comment: Yep, [Potatoswatter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/153285/potatoswatter) is right, that explains the other part of the statement. Hope this is helpful still.